# Changing encoding while merging in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding, version-control, tfs, git-merge

We're using TFS and Visual Studio's Source Control (2010) as version control tools in our Java project. There are two branches, one in cp1251 encoding (source), and other in UTF-8 (target). Is there any way to merge these two branches correctly? I mean, that the encoding of both the source and target branches should stay as they are now.
Sry for poor English and maybe incorrect question, I am new to version control tools

Comment: What was the encoding in the common ancestor?

Comment: Note: TFS and VS 2010 drop out of support this month (July 2015)